# OCL - calling rule

Tags: ocl, model-driven-development

What does the below code do? How can I write this OCL expression when there is one element instead of elements?

In other words, I don't understand which elements does the code collect?
Since "collect" is used when we have more than one element, if I have one element (instead of elements), what changes occure to "-> collect (s|thisModule.CreateMatchClass(s))" part of that expression?

```
s.source.elements -> collect (s|thisModule.CreateAnyMatchClass(s))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OCL expression simply 'create' elements (regarding the name of the `thismodule` function) from the elements that are in `s.source`. The created elements are then returned as a `Collection`:

- `s.source.elements` return (supposedly) a `Collection` (could be a `Set/Sequence...`) by navigating from `s`
- `collect(...)` gathers the results of its parameter expression

#### How to change the expression if the relation `elements` is not `0..*` anymore but `0..1` or `1..1`?

Indeed, `collect(...)` works with collections, but `->` is also an implicit converter to a `Set`. The page 15 of the OCL specification states:

> The "->" navigation shorthand performs an implicit set conversion of an object.
>
> `anObject->union(aSet)` is a shorthand for `anObject.oclAsSet()->union(aSet)`

It means that in the case `element` (I removed the final 's') is a "single" relationship and `s.source.element` returns a single element, the call `s.source.element->...` is equivalent to `s.source.element.oclAsSet()->...`. In your case, whether `elements` is many or not, the expression is still the same:

```
s.source.elements -> collect (s|thisModule.CreateAnyMatchClass(s))
```

This expression will work in both cases.

If you really don't want the `collect` and if you have your `elements` relationship which is single, you can write this also:

```
thisModule.createAnyMatchClass(s.source.elements)
```

Comment: when I write "class <- s.source -> collect (sipe|thisModule.CreateAnyMatchClass(sipe))" it doesn't create model (I have an error). Do you know what can I do? I attached my metamodel. "s" is refered to "TransformationRule" in metamodel.
(when I replace source with targets I have no error, when I change source reference to 0..* still it has an error)

Comment: At this point, your questions are not directly related to OCL but to ATL and the way it managed the transformation. I think you will have more chance to have a relevant answer in the Eclipse forum dedicated to ATL.

Comment: Thank you. it works with the last line of code you write. I was surprised when I restart eclipse it works!